# Issues trying to use If-None-Match with Etag in Android

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp, etag

Always returns code 200 (response ok) when it should be 304.

Here is my example code.

```kotlin
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Header
import retrofit2.http.Streaming
import retrofit2.http.Url

interface DownloadService {
    @Streaming
    @GET
    suspend fun downloadResourceIfNoneMatch(
        @Url url: String,
        @Header("If-None-Match") vararg eTags: String
    ): Response<ResponseBody?>
}
```

Here's my OkHttpClient that I am using:

```
val cacheSize: Long = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 100 MB
val cache = Cache(context.cacheDir, cacheSize)
val cacheControlInterceptor = CacheControlInterceptor(context)
return OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache)
    .addInterceptor(cacheControlInterceptor)
    .addNetworkInterceptor(cacheControlInterceptor)
    .addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    .build()
```

Here's my CacheControlInterceptor class:

```
import android.content.Context
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.IOException

class CacheControlInterceptor constructor(val context: Context) : Interceptor {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        Timber.d("cache control interceptor")
        var request: Request = chain.request()
        if (request.method == "GET") {
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .build()
        }
        val originalResponse: Response = chain.proceed(request)
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .header("Cache-Control", "private, must-revalidate")
            .build()
    }
}
```

Here is how I am making the request:

```
val response: Response<ResponseBody?> = downloadService.downloadResourceIfNoneMatch(downloadUrl, "2377a02e14b7df5100ee9ffebbb8443a")
```

I am using a hard-coded ETag for testing. When the request is made twice, it does not display the expected behavior (i.e. response code 304). The repeated request results in a null cacheResponse and a response code of 200.

I am seeing the expected debug log output, so it seems like the CacheControlInceptor is instantiating properly. I am getting the ETag in the response. The responses are caching properly in the context's cache directory. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp won't save the response to the cache unless you read it fully. It writes the cache as a side-effect of reading the response body.

If you stop reading before the response body is complete, OkHttp doesn't have a full response to store and the cache entry will not be available.

Comment: I saw a similar answer posted on a similar question. This didn't really help me since I believe I am posting reading the entire response body (though I could be wrong). I am reading the full response and closing out the stream upon completion.

Is there a way to check that the response has been read fully or not?

Do you happen to know where the OkHttp cache is in the device files, perhaps so I can double check? I assumed it would be stored in the user-specified cache folder in the internal app files.

Comment: You can use the Event Listener API to see all events including caching https://square.github.io/okhttp/caching/.  It could provide further explanation.